# Is it possible to ensure a certain schedule for the windows updates on a Windows Server 2016 using Powershell DSC?

Tags: windows-update, dsc

Part of configuration is to run all the Windows Updates. I am trying to figure out how to express it with Powershell DSC. Seems like the best is to ensure that the windows updates are scheduled regularly.

I found [xWindowsUpdateAgent](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWindowsUpdate) DSC resource, but it does not allow to specify the schedule itself, only to ensure that the updates are scheduled.

So, is it possible to ensure a concrete windows update schedule?

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can easily achieve the same by setting up the required registries, though I don't have any experience of DSC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xWindowsUpdateAgent is from the [xWindowsUpdate DSC module](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWindowsUpdate/tree/b10c090e8523a8129757b5a3a00ffbdd40dce813).
The resources can be used as part of a solution to a strictly defined schedule, but it's not complete by itself.

You can configure the machine in two ways:

1. Use `xWindowsUpdateAgent` to set the category, and source of updates.  Using ScheduledInstallation will rely on the local `Windows Update` schedule to download and install updates.
2. Use  `DSC`’s remediation schedule to drive update installs (exclusively or in addition to the Windows Update agent’s schedule).
   This requires using **UpdateNow** in your `xWindowsUpdateAgent` configuration, and setting the Local Configuration Manager’s Configuration Mode to **ApplyAndAutoCorrect**.
   Updates will be checked for and installed based on the **ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins**.
   You will also need to decide a reboot strategy for the updates, using either **RebootIfNeeded** or the machine’s reboot cycle for updating.

To achieve an absolute schedule, you could create a scheduled task to `Start-DSCConfiguration` on a configuration based on the second option above with **UpdateNow**.

This isn't the most straightforward approach, and would reevaluate any other settings in your configuration as well on the same schedule.

You could also use a scheduled task more directly to simply automate calls to the Windows Update Agent itself on a schedule (`wuauclt.exe /updatenow`), bypassing DSC.  Creating a task like this is certainly doable with DSC, but I don't know of any existing resource that does it all in one.  You'd need to write your own.

Comment: The readme for xWindowsUpdate module will be updated shortly at the git repository.

Comment: But it does not allow me to specify the schedule, does it?

Comment: You're right.  I focused in on the capabilities of the module once I ran into documentation errors.  I updated my answer.  Short version - you could add more code to get the job done partially using the module, but it's not a super natural fit.  There are more direct ways to do it.  DSC itself isn't a perfect fit for doing a doing a singular task on a rigid schedule, and this module doesn't cover all the configuration needed to create a strictly scheduled task for that singular purpose.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest how to enforce a certain windows updates schedule with DSC? Also, could you explain why you think it is not a good fit for DSC?

Comment: DSC itself normally runs on an interval, rather than a strict schedule.  You could certainly create a scheduled task to drive DSC via `Start-DSCConfiguration`  - but if you're going that route, you can just easily use DSC to create a scheduled task that drives the windows update agent directly.  Normally you wouldn't have a configuration that does a singular task, either.  Make sense?

Comment: I do not want DSC to run at a schedule. I need to ensure the Windows Updates are configured to run at a schedule. So, I am perfectly fine for DSC to check every 30 minutes that the Windows Update schedule is as specified in the configuration.

Comment: You're right.  We should probably start the answer over entirely, acknowledging xWindowsUpdate isn't going to be your solution (as you said in your question), and focus more on creating a configuration that uses a scheduled task to directly drive the Windows Update Agent.  There is another answer about creating a scheduled task to run a script.  That script could then call `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` .   See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175379/powershell-dsc-can-someone-please-provide-me-an-example-on-how-to-use-a-resourc